# Why does PHP SimpleXML children() returns null for empty tag?

Tags: php, xml, null, simplexml, children

We have following sample XML:

```
<xml>
    <call>
        <branchId>2</branchId>
        <item_main_display>1</item_main_display>
        <workstation_Id>1</workstation_Id>
        <formatted_ticket_number>203</formatted_ticket_number>
        <queue_letter></queue_letter>
        <service_Id>17</service_Id>
        <service_Name>konsultanti Queue</service_Name>
        <isflashing>false</isflashing>
        <workstation_Name>ServicePoint_D924</workstation_Name>
        <callTime>1442583923157</callTime>
        <timestamp>1442583923</timestamp>
        <eventTime>2015-09-18T17:45:23.114+0400</eventTime>
    </call>
</xml>
```

Using the followin PHP code we try to access all xml nodes;

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("sample.xml");

$xmlStr="";
$xmlStr.="<xml>";

foreach($xml->children() as $child1)
{
    $xmlStr.="<". $child1->getName().">";
    foreach($child1->children() as $child2){ 
        $xmlStr.="<". $child2->getName() .">". $child2 ."</". $child2->getName() .">";
    } 
    $xmlStr.="</". $child1->getName().">";
}
$xmlStr.="</xml>";
```

This Code works fine, Except: For tag

```
<queue_letter></queue_letter>
```

For this tag $child1->children() returns null; But if i enter space between tags

```
<queue_letter>     </queue_letter>
```

or newline, or any other character, the tag is returned.

Is this normal behaviour? How Can we return child tags that contain no character?

Thank You.

Comment: The code as provided in the question works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/uA6Fm (Although the whole thing could be simplified as `$xml->asXML()`, but I presume there's some reason you need to loop over it this way.)

Comment: Oh, and just FYI, `<xml>` is a reserved name, so the above XML is technically invalid. Again, probably just the way you've anonymised your example, but if you're actually using that tag I'd recommend changing it to avoid problems later.

Comment: Thank you. Very usefull.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a space between the tags, the tag isn't empty - he has one text node as it's child.

`<queue_letter></queue_letter>` is the same as `<queue_letter />` and this tag simply has no children, so it will always return null

Comment: Thank you.

But i want to access 

    <queue_letter></queue_letter> 

tag itself and get its name. The problem is - whole tag is null.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to solve this case following way: my PHP server contains resin.jar
I just downloaded latest version of it and replaced the original one. 
Everything works perfectly. Check this out: [Resin web server](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/resin-web-server.xtp)

Comment: I'm downvoting this because there is no explanation of what resin.jar is, where you found it, or what it has to do with the question. PHP components are not generally distributed in, or reliant on, JAR files.

Comment: I still don't understand what this has to do with PHP and SimpleXML. Are you using [Quercus](http://www.caucho.com/resin-3.1/doc/quercus.xtp) rather than the normal distribution of PHP, and this was a bug in their implementation of SimpleXML?

Comment: Yes, but i am not sure whether it was a bug in earlier versions, or they just changed the behaviour of the function.As earlier versions of it did not allow to retrieve a xml tag with empty content, but, obviously tags with empty content must be returned - i think it was a bug.